# Javascript + php form

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to make a contact form on my site.
Here's the code:

```
        <form id="form" method="post" action="send.php">
                <fieldset>
                  <label><input type="text" value="Email" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Email'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Email' ) this.value=''"></label>
                  <label><input type="text" value="App URL" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='App URL'" onFocus="if(this.value =='App URL' ) this.value=''"></label>                                             
                  <div class="btns"><a href="javascript:" class="button" onClick="document.getElementById('form').submit()">Send</a></div>
                </fieldset>  
        </form>
```

The problem is that the page send.php has nothing inside $_POST!

Is there someone who know how to solve it?
Thank you!

Comment: Don't abuse `value` as a substitute for a real label. It has nasty accessibility problems.

Comment: Don't use divs to replace buttons, you're creating an accessibility nightmare doing that. Please read this. http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/01/29/you-cant-create-a-button/ and if you insist http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201302/making_elements_keyboard_focusable_and_clickable/

Answer (score 1):

The inputs don't have names. Only inputs with names can be successful controls (and thus be submitted).

The names are used to determine the key in the associative array that PHP generates.

Answer (score 0):

Your input tags need a `name` attribute in order to appear in the `$_POST` array.

w3schools.com page to explain exact usage:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_name.asp